# Display instruction/function info on mouseover in eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have made my own editor by creating an eclipse plugin. I have implemented the code folding successfully and now I want to display instruction/function information on mouseover.
For example:
There is a instruction/function: print, in one of the file and this is used in other file(or may be same file), then on hovering over print it should display what it contains or may be comment written on top of it. How to achieve this?
Also I want to jump to the function print if user presses F3, as it happens in java editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:
In the `TextSourceViewerConfiguration` class(instantiated in Editor's initialize function), add the following code to instantiate the text hover class:

```
//global variable
private ITextHover hover_class
@Override
public ITextHover getTextHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer, String contentType) {
    if(hover_class==null)
        //instantiate the hover class
    return hover_class
```

Next, create the class that was instantiated in the previous step. It should implement `ITextHover`, `ITextHoverExtension`. The class `getHoverRegion()`, `getHoverInfo()`, `getHoverControCreator()` can be used to display needed information.